# Retrieve the names of (and default values of) the arguments accepted by a specified function

Tags: python, function, reflection

Say I have a function, `foo` which has some arguments...some positional and some keyword:

```
def foo(a, b=1.0, c=None):
    print a
    print c
    return 2 * b
```

Is there another function I can call with `foo` as an argument (or a method of `foo` which I can call) that will return to me a list of the positional arguments of `foo` as well as a list of tuples of the keyword arguments of foo along with their default values?  Specifically, calling:

```
the_function_i_want(foo)
```

should return

```
(('a',), (('b', 1.0), ('c', None)))
```

Or something like that.  To be clear I do *not* want a way to figure out what values were passed to `foo` one particular time that it was called.  Instead I want information about the function signature of `foo` in a programatic way.

(The use case I have in mind is to automatically make a web form which will be able to submit appropriate data to serve as the arguments of a specified function.  So that if I call `web_form(foo)` in the appropriate way, it will be able to render a web form with spaces for each of the arguments of `foo` with the default calling values pre-filled in an appropriate way.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're describing [`inspect.getargspec`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec):

```
>>> from inspect import getargspec
>>> getargspec(foo)
ArgSpec(args=['a', 'b', 'c'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=(1.0, None))
```

You can also use [`signature`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature) in 3.x:

```
>>> from inspect import signature
>>> signature(foo)
<Signature (a, b=1.0, c=None)>
```